# Google Appengine App.Yaml Handler

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to write a handler in google appengine using APP.YAML. I am trying to accomplish the following:

`/API/Module/Action/`  -> `api.php?module=**Module**&action=**Action**`

I have tried the following:

```
- url: /api/(.*)/(.*)
  script: api2.php?module=\2&action=\1  # specify a script
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
url: /api/(.*)/(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the result you are seeing?  You have reversed "module" and "action", and also have to handle that trailing slash.  Try:

```
- url: /api/(.*)/(.*)/
  script: api2.php?module=\1&action=\2  # specify a script
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- url: /api/(.*)/(.*)/
  script: api2.php
```

Then, inside your `api2.php` handler:

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $path);
// $segments[0] == "api"
module = $segments[1]
action = $segments[2]
```